# How can I use UNION and IN clause in single SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

My requirement is

```
Select *
from table
where I'd in(1,2,...2000) AND company ="XXX"
```

In SQL IN clause , it return 1000 rows only. Then I changed the code like

```
Select *
from table
where I'd in(1,2,3...1000) UNION ALL
select *
from table
where I'd in(1001...2000) AND company="XXX"
```

My question is " above query will give correct output or not?

If not, what is the solution?

Comment: No.  The `company` restriction is only on half the ids.

Comment: What is the solution for this?

Comment: Include the condition in both `where` clauses.

Comment: 'it return 1000 rows only' - check the default number of rows your ide will return (what is your ide by the way) and if unrestricted then that's all there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add company="XXX" in both the query as Gordon has already suggested.

```
Select * from table
where Id in(1,2,3...1000) AND company="XXX" 
UNION ALL
select * from table
where Id in(1001...2000) AND company="XXX"
```

If you are still getting thousands rows then try count(*) to know how many rows actually it's returning by below query:

```
Select * from (
where Id in(1,2,3...1000) AND company="XXX" 
UNION ALL
select * from table
where Id in(1001...2000) AND company="XXX") t
```

Comment: Thanks you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. Is your problem resolved? Please let me know

Comment: Resloved. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Always use column name instead of * in case of union all

Select * from (
where Id in(1,2,3...1000) AND company="XXX"
UNION ALL
select * from table
where Id in(1001...2000) AND company="XXX

Comment: Thank you so much♥️

Comment: if you are ok with the answer click write tick against my answer.that will help community to know that you got answer.

Comment: Sorry Nikil. kazi  answered this qns first.